# How to read a .txt file and convert to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am trying to use javascript to read a .txt file, but I cannot seem to find any methods online. The purpose of the code is to scan a text file for a certain string. In my code the user purposely uploads the file and it is stored in a variable, but i cannot find a way to actually read the text in the file and convert into a string. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
    document.getElementById("answer").addEventListener(search);
    document.getElementById("actualAns").addEventListener(search); 

    function myFunction() {
        var targetAns = document.getElementById("answer").value; //the user inputs a .txt file
        var actualAns = document.getElementById("actualAns").value; //the user enters the string they want to search
        var n = actualAns.search(targetAns); // this part does not work, it should search the text file but it only searches the name
        if(n > -1) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Correct";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file like this:

```
function readFile() {

  jQuery.get("file.txt", function(textString)) {

  //do what you want with the textString

  });
}
```

and in the textString you will have the string of text present in your file.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21458245)